Create link to SharePoint Library Default Form on another SharePoint page
I have a Library in SP Online where the Users create a new Document Set with data entered in the SP Default form.  I also want them to be able to launch this form from the main SharePoint page, but the link I used for the Button on that page won't launch the form, rather another screen to create a new folder.  I'm not sure why.  The link I'm using comes from clicking "Copy Link" when you open a new Form.  It's probably a setting I'm overlooking, but any help would be great.
Thank you.

Adding link to "new form" page on button click will NOT launch form in dialog/pop-up on same page. It will open link in new/same browser tab, there is no way to control this behavior with SharePoint out of the box features.

I'm fine with the user staying on the same tab.  my issue is that the link that I get from the form's "Copy Link" button takes you to a new screen to create a New Folder

Are you using Document Set in a document library? I tried copying the URL that creates Document into the button on the page. Everything worked fine and I managed to open the create Document Set page.


Yes this is a Document Set getting created in a Library.  The link that I get from the Copy Link button at the top of the form, takes you to a screen to create a new Folder, rather than the form to create a document set.

I was hoping to follow up on this.  I'm wondering if there's something in either the Library or Content Type's settings causing this behavior.  This is the URL I get from the Copy Link/Link to Form: https://MyCompany.sharepoint.com/sites/UC_ContractWF/_layouts/15/listform.aspx?PageType=8&ListId=%7B7C000AC3-CAA4-4502-9CE5-2A4D3BD0C742%7D&RootFolder=%2Fsites%2FUC_ContractWF%2Fcontracts&Source=https%3A%2F%2FMyCompany.sharepoint.com%2Fsites%2FUC_ContractWF%2Fcontracts%2FForms%2FAllItems.aspx&ContentTypeId=0x0120D520003271BA9C78E12B4D8E738CD47ADEC7A5008016A773CD7BF34CB23DAE9458027A5A

I'm not sure why, but adding this URL to a button in my Canvas app takes me to a New Folder form.  Not clue why.  I have Make New Folder command off as well.
